# How can I integrate a simple bootstrap-button within Yii (via CHtml) without any extensions?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, yii, icons, yii-chtml

How could I do that with CHtml (this works within Yii too) ?

```
<button class="btn btn-app btn-warning">
    <i class="icon-undo bigger-230"></i>
    Undo
</button>
```

I've tried the following without success:

```
echo CHtml::link('myLabelText',array('MyController/index'), array(
    'class' =>'cMyOwnClass btn btn-app btn-warning',
    'icon'=>'icon-undo',
));
```

I see the button, connection to MyController is OK, CSS-classes are OK, but there is no icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're providing the additional css info at the wrong place. Try this:

```
echo CHtml::link('<i class="icon-undo"></i> myLabelText',array('MyController/index'),array(
    'class'=>'cMyOwnClass btn btn-app btn-warning',
));
```

This will still generate a `<a href="...">...</a>`-style link, though.